# Игра "Smile"

Tags: c++

Доброго времени суток. Пишу игру "smile" (по типу танчиков на 8 битке ) - только намного проще , так вот смайлик враг выходит за пределы игрового поля , бьюсь с этой задачей несколько часов , посмотрите код свежим взглядом , помогите найти ошибку . Заранее благодарю.

Код:

```
#include<iostream>
#include <conio.h>
#include <Windows.h>
using namespace std;
void main()
{
    COORD smileCoord = { 35, 10 };//координаты смайла
    COORD enemyCoord1 = { 10, 5 };//координаты первого врага
    COORD enemyCoord2 = { 45, 15 };// координаты 2-го врага
    HANDLE hndl = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);//получаем дескриптор консоли
    SetConsoleTextAttribute(hndl, FOREGROUND_BLUE | FOREGROUND_RED | FOREGROUND_GREEN);//устанавливаем  белый цвет
    const int Y = 20, X = 70, MAX_SCORE = 400;
    int scores = 0, lives = 3;
    enum {SPACE, WALL, SCORES, LIVES, ESCAPE=27};
    enum DIRECTIONS{LEFT, RIGHT, UP, DOWN};
    DIRECTIONS enemyDir1 = DOWN;
    DIRECTIONS enemyDir2 = RIGHT;
#pragma region Game_field
    int a[Y][X] = { 
        1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
        1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1,
        1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1,
        1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1,
        1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1,
        1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1,
        1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1,
        1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1,
        1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1,
        1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1,
        1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1,
        1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1,
        1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1,
        1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1,
        1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1,
        1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1,
        1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1,
        1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1,
        1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1,
        1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
    };
#pragma endregion
#pragma region Draw_game_field
    for (int i = 0; i < Y; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < X; j++)
        {
            switch (a[i][j])
            {
            case SPACE: cout << ' ';
                break;
            case WALL: cout << '#';
                break;
            case SCORES:
                SetConsoleTextAttribute(hndl, FOREGROUND_GREEN | FOREGROUND_RED | FOREGROUND_INTENSITY);
                cout << '$';
                SetConsoleTextAttribute(hndl, FOREGROUND_GREEN | FOREGROUND_RED | FOREGROUND_BLUE);
                break;
            }
        }
        cout << '\n';
    }
#pragma endregion

    COORD scoresCoord = {5, 22};
    SetConsoleCursorPosition(hndl, scoresCoord);
    cout << "Scores: " << scores;
    COORD livesCoord = { 20, 22 };
    SetConsoleCursorPosition(hndl, livesCoord);
    cout << "Lives: " << lives;

    while (true)//Основной игровой цикл
    {
        //движение первого врага
        SetConsoleCursorPosition(hndl, enemyCoord1);
        cout << ' ';
        switch (enemyDir1)
        {
        case UP:
            if (a[enemyCoord1.Y - 1][enemyCoord1.X] == WALL) enemyDir1 = DOWN;
            else enemyCoord1.Y--;
            break;
        case DOWN:
            if (a[enemyCoord1.Y + 1][enemyCoord1.X] == WALL) enemyDir1 = UP;
            else enemyCoord1.Y++;
            break;
        }
        // движение второго врага
        SetConsoleCursorPosition(hndl, enemyCoord2);
        cout << ' ';
        switch (enemyDir2)
        {
        case LEFT:
            if (a[enemyCoord2.X - 1][enemyCoord2.Y] == WALL) enemyDir2 = RIGHT;
            else enemyCoord2.X--;
            break;
        case RIGHT:
            if (a[enemyCoord2.X + 1][enemyCoord2.Y] == WALL) enemyDir2 = LEFT;
            else enemyCoord2.X++;
            break;
        }
        //Проверка столкновения с врагом
        if (smileCoord.X == enemyCoord1.X && smileCoord.Y == enemyCoord1.Y)
        {
            lives--;
            SetConsoleCursorPosition(hndl, livesCoord);
            cout << "Lives: " << lives;
        }
        if (smileCoord.X == enemyCoord2.X && smileCoord.Y == enemyCoord2.Y)
        {
            lives--;
            SetConsoleCursorPosition(hndl, livesCoord);
            cout << "Lives: " << lives;
        }
        SetConsoleCursorPosition(hndl, enemyCoord1);
        SetConsoleTextAttribute(hndl, FOREGROUND_RED | FOREGROUND_INTENSITY);
        cout << (char)2;
        SetConsoleTextAttribute(hndl, FOREGROUND_BLUE | FOREGROUND_RED | FOREGROUND_GREEN);
        SetConsoleCursorPosition(hndl, enemyCoord2);
        SetConsoleTextAttribute(hndl, FOREGROUND_RED | FOREGROUND_INTENSITY);
        cout << (char)2;
        SetConsoleTextAttribute(hndl, FOREGROUND_BLUE | FOREGROUND_RED | FOREGROUND_GREEN);
        if (_kbhit())//если нажата любая клавиша
        {
            SetConsoleCursorPosition(hndl, smileCoord);
            cout << ' ';
            switch (_getch())//анализируем код нажатой клавиши
            {
            case 'w':
            case 'W':
                if (a[smileCoord.Y-1][smileCoord.X] != WALL) smileCoord.Y--;
                break;
            case 's':
            case 'S':
                if (a[smileCoord.Y+1][smileCoord.X] != WALL) smileCoord.Y++;
                break;
            case 'a':
            case 'A':
                if (a[smileCoord.Y][smileCoord.X-1] != WALL) smileCoord.X--;
                break;
            case 'd':
            case 'D':
                if (a[smileCoord.Y][smileCoord.X+1] != WALL) smileCoord.X++;
                break;
            case ESCAPE://Escape
                exit(1);
            }
            //Проверка столкновения с врагом
            if (smileCoord.X == enemyCoord1.X && smileCoord.Y == enemyCoord1.Y)
            {
                lives--;
                SetConsoleCursorPosition(hndl, livesCoord);
                cout << "Lives: " << lives;
            }
            if (smileCoord.X == enemyCoord2.X && smileCoord.Y == enemyCoord2.Y)
            {
                lives--;
                SetConsoleCursorPosition(hndl, livesCoord);
                cout << "Lives: " << lives;
            }

            switch (a[smileCoord.Y][smileCoord.X])
            {
            case SCORES:
                scores += 100;
                a[smileCoord.Y][smileCoord.X] = 0;
                SetConsoleCursorPosition(hndl, scoresCoord);
                cout << "Scores: " << scores;
                if (scores == MAX_SCORE)
                {
                    COORD coord = {35, 12};
                    SetConsoleCursorPosition(hndl, coord);
                    cout << "CONGRATULATIONS!!!";
                    _getch();
                    exit(1);
                }
                break;
            }
        }
        if (lives == 0)
        {
            system("cls");
            COORD coord = { 35, 12 };
            SetConsoleCursorPosition(hndl, coord);
            cout << "G A M E  O V E R!";
            _getch();
            exit(1);
        }
        SetConsoleCursorPosition(hndl, smileCoord);//Позиционируем смайл
        SetConsoleTextAttribute(hndl, FOREGROUND_GREEN|FOREGROUND_INTENSITY);//задаем цвет и интенсивность смайла
        cout << (char)1;//выводим смайл
        Sleep(100);
    }

    SetConsoleTextAttribute(hndl, FOREGROUND_BLUE | FOREGROUND_RED | FOREGROUND_GREEN);//возвращаем белый цвет
    _getch();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Попробуйте сравнить координаты с 0 перед тем, как вычитать 1

```
case 'W':
                if (a[  smileCoord.Y-1  ][smileCoord.X] != WALL)
```

Comment: Можно конкретнее что Вы имеете ввиду замену в If -1 на 0 или что то другое ?

Comment: вот до этого момента **a[smileCoord.Y-1]** проверить, не выходит ли за границы массива, т.е. сравнить с 0.

> если число будет за границами, то он не сможет обратиться к массиву